# Right click on Lenovo U410 not working in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lenovo

I managed to install Ubuntu 12.04 on the [Lenovo Ideapad U410](http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/gbweb/LenovoPortal/en_GB/catalog.workflow%3acategory.details?current-catalog-id=FD6DB49790C7411D933567FC361231FB&current-category-id=30B029355DE401273E507312EE07809E&action=init), however the right-click is not working out of the box. To be more specific, instead of working as a right click it works like a normal left click.

I did already find a solution for the Lenovo U310 by creating a 51-synaptics.conf file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d which looks as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
MatchDriver "synaptics"
Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"

Option "LockedDrags" "1"
Option "BottomEdge" "4000"
Option "AreaBottomEdge" "4445"

EndSection
```

The solution has been found over at the [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966016)

Using that code however led to the right-click working only when clicking the touchpad at a very specific spot which was too small to hit reliably.

I am fairly sure that the config file merely needs a little tweaking, however I have no idea on what to do, so any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the value

`Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"`

to

`Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 100% 82% 0 0 0 0 0"`

This should make the whole bottom right half act as the right button.